# Java - Create a directory and add files from aws

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am trying to retrieve files from AWS and store them in a directory. I keep getting the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Temp\UPDATE_TEMP_5190592302690883358\aws (Access is denied)
```

Here is the code where it throws the error:

```
    File outputFile = new File(tmpDirPath + File.separator + "aws");

    outputFile.mkdirs();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
```

It complains before creating the FileOutputStream. I have tried outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs(); as well but it creates aws as type File instead of a directory. Can someone explain why it throws access denied on the directory?

Comment: Does the directory already exist when you run this code?

Comment: No it does not, but i do see it create the directory.

Answer (score 0):

According to official javadoc, calling [`mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) create all the parent directories for the given path, which is considered as a directory. As a consequence, if you check what did happened, you'll discover that `C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Temp\UPDATE_TEMP_5190592302690883358\aws` is not a file, but a directory.

I suggest you to replace

```
outputFile.mkdirs(); // which creates all directories, outputFile included
```

by

```
outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs(); // creates all directories up to outputFile's parent
                                     // outputFile will then be created as a file due to the FileOutputWriter
```

which will create the parent directory. You'll then be able to write in the new file.

Comment: The opposite is happening for me. Without the getParentFile call I am getting a directory, which is what I want. But with the getParentFile call I am getting a file

Comment: @user3562751 I've updated code to clarify things. Anyway, what's happening is the standard behaviour